# Get Instagram profile picture of commenting user using Instagram Graph API

Tags: instagram-graph-api

Is there a way to get profile pictures of users who comment on my Instagram Business Account page?

I have [Page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens#pagetokens), but I couldn't find a way to do this via official API.